# Getting Error in my Spring Application

Tags: spring, cxf

I'm developing a Spring/CXF-RESTful/MyBatis Application.
I always solved some errors myself, but this error....i don't know way to solve it.
So, please check this error and share our knowledge.
thanks.
jeong-sik.

```
![Project View][1]
```

**Error Log(JBoss)**

```
11:22:56,614 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
11:22:57,379 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
11:22:57,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) starting
11:23:01,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found cxfdbsample.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called cxfdbsample.war.dodeploy
11:23:01,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found blog.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called blog.war.dodeploy
11:23:01,280 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
11:23:01,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:23:01,292 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
11:23:01,314 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.18.GA-redhat-1
11:23:01,368 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:23:01,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:23:01,379 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
11:23:01,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1
11:23:01,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
11:23:01,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:23:01,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:23:01,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
11:23:01,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.23.Final-redhat-1)
11:23:01,691 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:23:02,508 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final-redhat-1
11:23:02,513 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\deployments
11:23:02,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "cxfdbsample.war" (runtime-name: "cxfdbsample.war")
11:23:02,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
11:23:02,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
11:23:02,598 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:23:02,608 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:23:02,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:23:34,418 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,419 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,420 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,420 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,422 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,422 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,422 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,423 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:34,451 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /C:/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/cxfdbsample.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:23:39,141 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment cxfdbsample.war
11:23:39,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:23:39,445 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: cxfdbsample.war
11:23:39,678 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900 1.1.16 (redhat)
11:23:39,778 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment cxfdbsample.war
11:23:40,961 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) JBAS018210: Register web context: /cxfdbsample
11:23:41,023 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cxfdbsample]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
11:23:41,073 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cxfdbsample]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11:23:41,073 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
11:23:41,309 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 11 11:23:41 KST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
11:23:41,482 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]
11:23:41,606 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
11:23:41,684 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]
11:23:42,056 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mybatis/mybatis-context.xml]
11:23:42,552 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mybatis/jdbc.properties]
11:23:42,569 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
11:23:44,707 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restContainer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/EndpointInfo;)Lorg/apache/cxf/transport/Destination;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/EndpointInfo;)Lorg/apache/cxf/transport/Destination;
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:93) [cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:72) [cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:160) [cxf-bundle-3.0.0-milestone1.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cxfdbsample</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxfdbsample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>cxfdbsample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mybatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mybatis spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- apache commons dbcp-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CXF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-milestone2</version>         
        </dependency>            

        <!--  RESTful -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-ea</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jra</groupId>
            <artifactId>jra</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
           <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
           <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
           <version>2.4</version>
          </dependency>         
     </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>cxfdbsample</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>cxfdbsample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  

  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
                org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

   <!-- CXF -->
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cxfdbsample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxfdbsample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/beans.xml
            /WEB-INF/mybatis/mybatis-context.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

**beans.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
                        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<!-- 
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-binding.xml" />
 --> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="cxfdbsample.controller" /> 

    <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="loginController" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
<!-- 
     <bean id="loginController" class="cxfdbsample.controller.LoginController" /> 
 -->
</beans>
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package cxfdbsample.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET; import javax.ws.rs.Path; import javax.ws.rs.PathParam; import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray; import net.sf.json.JSONObject;



//@Controller import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

//@Service import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

//@WebService import javax.jws.WebService; //@WebParam import javax.jws.WebParam;

//@HttpResource import org.codehaus.jra.HttpResource;

//@Resource import javax.annotation.Resource;



//import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;




import cxfdbsample.mybatis.UserDaoImpl; import cxfdbsample.vo.UserVo; import cxfdbsample.util.Util;

//@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://localhost:8080/cxfdbsample/") @Path("user") @Service("loginController") public class LoginController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);    UserVo userVo;

    @Resource(name="userDaoImpl")   private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
         // @HttpResource(location = "/loginController/{id}/{password}") // public JSONObject UserCheck(@WebParam(name = "id") String id, @WebParam(name = "password") String password){    @GET    @Path("user/{id}/{password}")   public JSONObject UserCheck(@PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("password") String password){
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String userId = Util.nullCheck(id, "");         String userPassword = Util.nullCheck(password, "");     
                map.put("id",userId);       map.put("password", userPassword);
                int loginValue = 0;
                try {  loginValue = userDaoImpl.getLoginResult(map);  } catch (Exception e) { }

                if (loginValue == 1)        {           logger.info("로그인성공");           userVo = userDaoImpl.getUserInfo(id);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();           JSONArray cell = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();          obj.put("userId", userVo.getUserId());          obj.put("userPassword", userVo.getUserPassword());          obj.put("userEmail", userVo.getUserEmail());            obj.put("userName", userVo.getUserName());          obj.put("userSeq", userVo.getUserSeq());            cell.add(obj);              jsonObject.put("data", cell);
                        System.out.println(jsonObject);             return jsonObject;  
             //         for(int i = 0; i < userVo.size(); i++){ //               //             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); //               obj.put("userId", userVo.getUserId()); //               obj.put("userPassword", userVo.getUserPassword()); //               obj.put("userEmail", userVo.getUserEmail()); //             obj.put("userName", userVo.getUserName()); //               obj.put("userSeq", userVo.getUserSeq()); //              //             cell.add(obj);   //         } //            jsonObject.put("data", cell);       }       else        {           //수정 필요 부분          logger.info("로그인실패");           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();           JSONArray cell = new JSONArray();                   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();          obj.put("userId", null);            obj.put("userPassword", null);          obj.put("userEmail", null);             obj.put("userName", null);          obj.put("userSeq", null);           cell.add(obj);              jsonObject.put("data", cell);               System.out.println(jsonObject);             return jsonObject;          }   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I also got the error

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/EndpointInfo;)Lorg/apache/cxf/transport/Destination;
```

For me, the problem was that two different versions of CXF were on the classpath (some 2.6 or 2.7 and some 3.0). After making sure that only one version would be used, the error message disappeared. I haven't checked your POM though, because you'll probably already have solved the issue after 2 years :)